# How to use RelativeDateTimeFormatter second interval with a date?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, date, nsdateformatter

I store the date of events in firebase. I have the second, minute, hour, day, week, and year for each event but when I want to use the RelativeDateTimeFormatter it requires the total seconds from the the event to the current date. How to get this with the available information or how do I use this better? The code:

```
let exampleDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(-15000)
let formatter = RelativeDateTimeFormatter()
formatter.unitsStyle = .full
let relativeDate = formatter.localizedString(for: exampleDate, relativeTo: Date())
cell.timeLabel.text = "\(relativeDate)"
```

I have date information in indexRow such as payment.day but whats the correct format and way to make the ReletiveDateTimeFormatter work for me and show me Ex. 2 days ago successfully using my Firebase data?

Comment: You should store dates in firebase. Don't store discrete components. One of the problems with storing discrete components is you need to worry about Timezone. You can use `DateComponents` to reconstitute a `Date` from discrete components but best to avoid the problem in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, how do I convert the date though to seconds for the Formatter or what's a better way?

Comment: @Lukeksaunders you can use Date property `timeIntervalSinceNow`. Btw you should store the date instead of its components in firebase (as timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate or as a ISO8601 string).

Comment: Store [`timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1780268-timeintervalsincereferencedate) in Firebase. Then you can easily recreate a [`Date`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1779647-init) instance when you need it.  And time zones will automatically be accounted for.